# Set custom environment to root user from normal user (sudo -i)

Tags: bash, sudo

How to set custom variables like bash prompt,aliases,etc after becoming root from normal users using sudo -i

Login via Putty (key based) with "nir" username  -> Become root using sudo -i

After root i can see `echo $SUDO_USER` gives my username "nir"

I don't want this changes to be permanent so not thinking of `/root/.bashrc`

One way which i think is of creating a script and putting in my home directory and putting entry in `/root/.bashrc` (working on this)

Any comments.

--thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script at `/root/.bash_nir` with the custom settings/commands such as:

```
export SOME_VAR=user_nir
```

then add to `/root/.bashrc` the following:

```
[[ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]] && [[ -f "$HOME/.bash_$SUDO_USER" ]] && source "$HOME/.bash_$SUDO_USER"
```

Now when you `sudo -i` as the nir user bash will execute the extra script, but not if you log into root via other means. This will also work for any other user simply by creating a script for them as `/root/.bash_$USERNAME`.